# Angular: JSON html markup with angular component dynamic

Tags: php, angular, dynamic

**EDIT 1:**

Thank you for @Narm for the solution. I got it working!

In `let myTemplate = '<div class="test" (tap)="test();">Test</div>';`, I have a tap function.

When I click on it to invoke the function, it does not work and gives an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: _co.another_test is not a function
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
ngOnInit(){ 
   ...
    let myTemplate = `<div class="test" (tap)="test();">Test</div>`;
   ...
}

test(){
  console.log("Test");
}
```

Any thoughts?

---

**Original Question Below**

From php using REST, I am getting html markup with Angular components:

**From php:**

```
function send_html(){
    $html = '<div class="test" *ngIf="data">This is an example</div>';
    return $html;
};
```

Then in my angular project, I am trying to add this html dynamically using `componentFactoryResolver`: (I understand that it only accepts Angular component)

**Here is my though process:**

1. In `main.ts` (shown below): call the `getDynamicREST()` and get the `$html` from php.
2. When the data is fetched, then send this to `my_component.ts` to make this as an Angular component.
3. Once the html markup becomes a part of Angular component, then use `createComponent` to create the component.

Of course, it doesn't work...

This is what I have so far: Please feel free to tear it apart.

**main.html**

```
<div class="top">
   <ng-template #main></ng-template>
</div>
```

**main.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewContainerRef  } from '@angular/core';
import { my_component } from './my_component';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-main_page',
    templateUrl: 'main_page.html'
})
export class main_page {        
    @ViewChild('main', { read: ViewContainerRef }) entry: ViewContainerRef;
    data: any;

constructor(public resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
            public mine: my_component ){    

};      

    ngOnInit(){ 
        this.getDynamicREST().then((res)=>{
            this.mine.data = res;

            const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(my_component);
            this.entry.createComponent(factory);

        })
    };

}
```

**my_component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'my_component ',
    template: '<div class="my_component">{{data}}</div>'
})

export class my_component {
   data: any;
}
```

How would I achieve this so that I can fetch angular components dynamically and display them?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right path. I ran into this very same scenario just a few months ago, here is the solution to accomplish your goals.

Here I attached a StackBlitz if you want to see the code running live and have a chance to play with it. Dynamic components can be a challenge to understand at first.

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mlc-app-init-bshr1x)

#### app.component.ts

This component acts as the container to the dynamic component and is where it will be created.

```
import {
  Component, ViewChild, OnInit, OnDestroy,
  AfterViewInit, ComponentFactoryResolver,
  Input, Compiler, ViewContainerRef, NgModule,
  NgModuleRef, Injector
} from '@angular/core';


import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';


@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('vc', { read: ViewContainerRef }) _container: ViewContainerRef;
  private cmpRef;

  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private compiler: Compiler,
    private _injector: Injector,
    private _m: NgModuleRef<any>) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let myTemplate = `<h2> Generated on the fly</h2>
                      <p>You can dynamically create your component template!</p>`

    @Component({ 
      template: myTemplate 
      })
      class dynamicComponent {
        constructor(){}
    }
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule
      ],
      declarations: [dynamicComponent]
    })class dynamicModule {};
    const mod = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(dynamicModule);
    const factory = mod.componentFactories.find((comp) =>
      comp.componentType === dynamicComponent
    );

    this.cmpRef = this._container.createComponent(factory);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.cmpRef) {
      this.cmpRef.destroy();
    }
  }
}
```

Then in the template for your app component

#### app.component.html

`<ng-template #vc></ng-template>`

Then in your app.module you need to import the compiler and declare it as a provider:

#### app.module.ts

```
import {Compiler, COMPILER_OPTIONS, CompilerFactory} from '@angular/core';
import {JitCompilerFactory} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
export function createCompiler(compilerFactory: CompilerFactory) {
  return compilerFactory.createCompiler();
}



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: COMPILER_OPTIONS, useValue: {}, multi: true},
    {provide: CompilerFactory, useClass: JitCompilerFactory, deps: [COMPILER_OPTIONS]},
    {provide: Compiler, useFactory: createCompiler, deps: [CompilerFactory]}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

### *** Edit for 'tap' question

What you want to do is bind to the (click) event, I am not aware of any (tap) events and there are none listed in the Events reference by MDN [Events Reference MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)

In your dynamic component add the following:

```
let myTemplate = `<h2> Generated on the fly</h2>
                      <p>You can dynamically create your component template!</p>
                      <div class="test" (click)="test();">Test</div>`

    @Component({ 
      template: myTemplate 
      })
      class dynamicComponent {
        constructor(){}

        public test(){
          alert("I've been clicked!");
        }
    }
```

**Note I updated the StackBlitz if you want to see it in action!**

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the help! I got it working, or one step closer. It now finally shows the html markup properly. However the `(tap)` function still does not work. I added more detail in the question in `Edit 1` section. Any thoughts would be much appreciated! =)

Comment: Updated for the additional quiestion :)

Comment: Well, you are awesome! =) Thanks for your help! =)

Comment: FYI, it says I need to wait 18 hours before I can award the bounty. I will remember to do it tomorrow! =)